# Issue after editing Search Properties in coded UI?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

We are using coded ui test using visual studio 2010.We are testing .Net 4.0 windows application.

Here is an scenario.

We have an windows app which has a button named submit and we have recorded a workflow which clicks on submit.
Now when we generate code using coded ui the serach criteria for the button is based on its name (display name of button).

If tommorrow developer changes the button's text to submit1 , our scripts fail.

We tried using "controlName"[name given to the control and not the display name] property in search criteria instead of Name , but it does not work.

We get following error - **"The playback failed to find the control with the given search properties"**

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please be specific about what technology you are using? Is it `Android` or `iOS` or something else? We will not be able to understand what you are trying to ask if you don't specify it. Please provide appropriate tags.

Comment: See the reply from Vicky Song on http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/vsautotest/thread/c6abc11f-84e0-4226-a299-db72277bf7d6

Comment: Also I would like to mention that without proper tagging questions that are vague are not likely to be noticed more.

Answer (score 0):

Related problem happens to me also. I solved it by sending the Focus to the UI control before using that control. 
Try this.

this.UIAssettePresentationsWindow2.UINOWindow.UINOButton.SetFocus();